# Xcode can't find XMPPFramework--how do you fix linker errors?

Tags: ios, xcode4, build, linker, xmppframework

this must be a prevalent problem, but I'd appreciate any help. I have an Xcode 4.2 project that just won't build without errors.  The issue is XMPPFramework for iOS.  I have followed the directions on the wiki already.

I don't really understand at a deep level what is going on, but Xcode can't find my XMPPFramework (for iOS).  Here is the error, and I don't know how to fix it. I have added the path to XMPPFramework in the project and target settings. My XMPPFramework files are located  is at the root of my Xcode project already, yet Xcode can't seem to find the files. What is a user header path, framework path, and library search path? I have added the path to XMPPFramework to all of these fields without any benefit. I've used $(inherited) and $(SRCROOT) and checked the recursive button.  All my points to whoever can help me fix this.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_ExtractFileNameWithoutExtension", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone contextDidSave:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone xmppStreamDidSecure:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone xmppStreamDidConnect:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         -[AppDelegate_iPhone xmppStream:didReceiveMessage:] in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         ...   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDTTYLogger", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPStream", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPReconnect", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPRoster", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPvCardTempModule", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPvCardAvatarModule", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPCapabilities", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPPresence", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPJID", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate_iPhone.o
>         objc-class-ref in AccountViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in AddBuddyViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in ChatViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in GroupChatViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, figured it out.  You can't just drag and drop the files into the project. You must copy them into the project folder, then add them.

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on, I would like to say, if you're using Xcode 4.6.1 or later, then the routine of copying files into project folder and dragging-dropping them to Xcode also won't resolve this Linker error.

The workaround here would be to create "Groups" yourself in the Xcode project(Right Click->New Group) and then add the respective files/folders into those groups by dragging-dropping them. Make sure, not to check "Copy files into source folder" option. However, make sure to check the "Add to target" option. To know what Groups to create, you can have a look at their sample XMPP project. Create them in same hierarchy, as shown in that project.

Also make sure you have included CoreData.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework into the Frameworks.

If somehow, you still fail to get it working, I would suggest you to have a look at sample XMPP project included in the XMPPFramework master copy you downloaded from their Git link. Check how they have arranged the files in groups and the folder structure of their project. Just follow the suite and you should be good.